# Uploading an image, then displaying it as a Canvas on the next page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, canvas

I'm attempting to create a page that allows the manipulation of an uploaded image by using Canvas. So far, I've had no luck forwarding the image from one page (the submit form) to the other, which contains the canvas. I'm using PHP, Javascript and HTML in order to try and send the image from the submit form to the canvas space.

This is the submitting form.

```
  <form action="designer.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name">Name</label><?php
      include('/tbp3/php/autoload.php');
      header('Content-Type: application/json');
      $fullpath = $_SESSION['activeImg'];
      $size = getimagesize($fullpath);
      echo json_encode(array('x' => $size[0], 'y' => $size[1], 'path' => $fullpath, 'lastPosJson' => isset($_SESSION['lastPos']) ? $_SESSION['lastPos'] : '[]'));
      $db->close();
      ?>
      <p>2-32 characters</p>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">

      <p>JPEG/PNG under 2MB only</p>
      <label class="btn btn-default" for="image">Choose Image</label>
      <span></span>
      <input class="inputfile" type="file" name="image" id="canvas">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Next">
  </form>
```

This is the JavaScript I use in order to confirm the uploaded file is a PNG or JPEG. Note: I'm a novice at Javascript.

```
var validTypes = ['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg'];

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').submit(function(e){//on submission..
        var file = $('#upload').val();
        var isValid = true;
        var error = '';

        if(file == ''){
            error = 'Select a file before proceeding!';
            $('#upload').addClass('validation-error');
            isValid = false;
        } else{
            var type = /[^\.]*$/.exec(file).toString().toLowerCase();
            if($.inArray(type, validTypes) == -1){ 
                error = type + ' is an invalid type for the image! Please use ' + validTypes.join(', ').replace(/,([^,]*)$/, " or$1.");
                $('#upload').addClass('validation-error');
                isValid = false;
            }
        }
});
```

And this is on the page 'Designer.php'. I want the image to be displayed on the  tag.

```
<div class="row canvasarea">
    <div class="col-xs-6 header">Canvas</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 header">Live View</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row canvasarea">
        <div class="col-xs-6 help">TEXT</div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 help">TEXT</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row canvasarea">
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                <canvas id='canvas'></canvas></div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                        <img id='liveupdate'/><br></div>
```

The PHP script I'm using to save it to the server.

```
<?php
require('/var/www/html/tpb3/php/autoload.php');
session_start();

$megabyte = 8000000;
$db = "new Database();";

function getImage(){
    $id = $this->getTemplateId();
    $type = $this->getFiletype();
    return "img/template/$id.$type";
 }

function addTemplate($templateId, $filetype){
    if(!$this->isLoggedIn()){
    echo "You're not logged in";
        return '';
    }


function isValidFileType($type){
    $type = strtolower($type);
    $types = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png');
    for($i = 0; $i < count($types); $i++){
        if($type === $types[$i]){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function isPng($filepath){
    $img = @imagecreatefrompng($filepath);
    if($img === false){
        return false;
    } else{
    echo "Not a PNG";
        imagedestroy($img);
        return true;
    }
}

function isJpeg($filepath){
    $img = @imagecreatefromjpeg($filepath);
    if($img === false){
        return false;
    } else{
    echo "Not a JPEG";
        imagedestroy($img);
        return true;
    }
}

if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]) || $_SESSION["loggedin"] !== true){
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}

if(!empty($_POST['selectedType']) ){
    $selectedType = $_POST['type'];
}

if(isset($_POST["type"]))

$selectedType = $_POST["type"];
$dir = $selectedType == 'template' ? 'temp' : 'sourceimages';

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {


    $valid = true;
    $id = uniqid();
    $type = strtolower(pathinfo(basename($_FILES['upload']['name']), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $uploadFileDest = 'img/template/$id.$type';
    $size = @getimagesize($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]);
    $error = '';

    if($size === false) {
        $error .= "Main image not a valid image, ";
        $valid = false;
    } elseif($size[0] > 2000 || $size[1] > 2000){
        $error .= "Image larger than 2000px, ";
        $valid = false;
    } elseif(!isValidFileType($type)){
        $error .= "Not a valid filetype, ";
        $valid = false;
    } elseif(!isJpeg($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"]) && !isPng($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"])){
        $error .= "Image is not a valid jpg/png. ";
        $valid = false;
    } elseif ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] > 2 * $megabyte) {
        $error .= "File larger than 2 MB, ";
        $valid = false;
    }
}

    if($valid = true){
        if($selectedType == 'template'){
            $_SESSION['activeId'] = $id;
            $_SESSION['activeImg'] = $uploadFileDest;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $uploadFileDest);
            header('Location: designer.php');
        } else{
            $response = $db->addSourceImage($id, $type);
            if($response == ';success'){
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"], $uploadFileDest);
                $_SESSION['lastId'] = $id;
                header('Location: success.php');
            } else{
                header('Location: submit.php?e='.urlencode("Database failed with message: $response"));
            }
        }
    } else{
        header('Location: submit.php?e='.urlencode(substr($error, 0, strlen($error) - 2)));
    }
}

?>
```

Any push into the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have error messages either in the server logs or the browser's console?

Comment: The only error message I'm getting from both the server logs and the browser's console is as followed;
```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
Uncaught ReferenceError: translate is not defined
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (submit-validation.js:35) which is removed
    at HTMLFormElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLFormElement.r.handle
```
Form Element (submit-validation) has been removed from the JavaScript, but it remains active in the PHP page.

Comment: Is this error in the server log or the browser console?

Comment: This is in the browser console. I can't appear to find anything in the server log.

Comment: Is server error logging enabled?

Comment: Please include the PHP script that you're using to save the file serverside, (or JS script that stores the image in the browser e.g. localStorage, if you're doing that, idk). Atm - I don't see how/where you're saving the image that you want to display on next page.

Comment: I included the PHP script. PHP server logging has been enabled, but no errors occur at the launching of the PHP file.

Comment: I don't know how you expect this to work. You're calling `$this->` when not working inside class. You're calling `$db->addSourceImage` where `$db` is a string; your closing brackets don't match opening ones (i'll attribute that to copypasting). The problem here is (I guess, causing your code not being able to enter your if statements) that you're naming your file `image`, but you're checking for `$_FILES['upload']` serverside, yet you'd still get exceptions for the issues I've highlighted. Where did you get this code?

Comment: The source is as follows: https://github.com/shitpostbotbr/ShitpostBOTBR